# Word 2010 POL Save As PDF Error

Tags: wine, pdf, playonlinux, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I have been running Word 2010 through PlayOnLinux (POL v4.2.10 with Wine v2.22) on Ubuntu 16.04 for a while without any problems. I recently started getting the error "This file could not be found" when I try to save the Word document as a PDF.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this problem's been bothering me for months, I discovered the answer right after I posted the question!

In the Word <kbd>Save As</kbd> dialogue box, select PDF at <kbd>Save as type</kbd> and then click <kbd>Options</kbd>. Now **untick** <kbd>ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)</kbd>.

[image]